# xcode 11.4 does not have storyboard template

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, xcode-storyboard

I am following a lesson to develop an iPhone app using a storyboard.
In xcode 11.4, when starting a new project the storyboard template is not offered.
Am I suppose to use a different template and adapt it?

Comment: Update your question with what you are expecting to see and what you are seeing. What do you mean by storyboard template? Xcode 11 changed the way you choose the user interface for new projects. Use the User Interface menu button to choose Storyboard when you create a project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you had picked up SwiftUI instead of Storyboard.